# regex to match html tags with specific attributes

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am trying to match all HTML tags that do not have the attribute "term" or "range"

here is sample HTML format

```
<span class="inline prewrap strong">DATE:</span>    12/01/10
<span class="inline prewrap strong">MR:</span>  1234567
<span class="inline prewrap strong">DOB:</span> 12/01/65
<span class="inline prewrap strong">HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS:</span>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

<span class="inline prewrap strong">MEDICATIONS:</span>  <span term="Advil" range="true">Advil </span>and Ibuprofen.
```

My regex is: `<(.*?)((?!\bterm\b).)>`

Unfortunately this matches all the tags...It would be nice if the inner text wouldn't be matched as i need to filter out all the tags except the ones with that specific attribute.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about what you're trying to do? Are you trying to filter out all tags that _have_ a "term" or a "range" attribute or all of the tags _without_ a "term" or a "range" attribute?

Comment: i'm trying to filter out all the tags that DO NOT have "term" and "range" attribute. Basically after i do a replace() only the tags that have those attributes should still be there.

Answer (score 16):

If regex is your thing for this, this works for me.
(Note - filterring out comments, doctype and other entities is not included.
Other warnings; tags could be embeded in script, comments and other things.)

***span*** tag (***w/ attr***) no term|range attrs

```
'<span
  (?=\s)
  (?! (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) (?:term|range) \s*= )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
>'
```

***any*** tag (***w/ attr***) no term|range attrs

```
'<[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*
  (?=\s)
  (?! (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) (?:term|range) \s*= )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
>'
```

***any*** tag (***w/o attr***) no term|range attrs

```
'<
  (?:
    [A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*
    (?=\s)
    (?! (?:[^>"\']|(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'))*? (?<=\s) (?:term|range) \s*= )
    \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ 
  |
    /?[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s*/?
  )
>'
```

**Update**

Alternative to using (?>) construct
Below regex's are for no-'term|range'-attributes
Flags = (g)global and (s)dotall

***span tag w/attr***
link: http://regexr.com?2vrjr
regex: `<span(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)(?:term|range)\s*=)(?!\s*/?>)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+>`

***any tag w/attr***
link: http://regexr.com?2vrju
regex: `<[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)(?:term|range)\s*=)(?!\s*/?>)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+>`

***any tag w/attr or wo/attr***
link: http://regexr.com?2vrk1
regex: `<(?:[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)(?:term|range)\s*=)(?!\s*/?>)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+|/?[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s*/?)>`

***'to match every tag except the ones that have term="occasionally"'***

link: http://regexr.com?2vrka
`<(?:[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*(?=\s)(?!(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)term\s*=\s*(["'])\s*occasionally\s*\1)(?!\s*/?>)\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+|/?[A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*\s*/?)>`

Comment: Hi, i was trying your regex in this sample http://regexr.com?2vrg3 Please give it a look. It doesn't seem to match. Try for example to match every tag except the ones that have term="occasionally". This should give you the impression of what i'm trying to achieve. I still haven't fixed this, the regex I wrote comes close to the expected result but fails if there is another attribute besides term and range. Thank you

Comment: @user253530 - 3 problems; 1.you left spaces in the regex, 2.flag dotall not set, 3.this engine doesn't like possesive form `(?>exp)`. Added alternative regex(s) and links in my update.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use an HTML parser to solve this problem. Creating own regular expression is possible but erroneous for sure. Imagine that your code contains such expression

```
< span      class = "a"              >b< / span         >
```

It is also valid, but to consider all possible spaces and TAB characters in your regular expression would be not easy and would require testing before you can be sure that it works as it is expected.

Comment: I think the knee-jerk reaction to avoiding regular expression where XML is concerned is inappropriate in this case. A single tag is a well-defined item and, apart from tags appearing within a comment, can easily be found by a regex.

Comment: <[\s]*?span[^>]*?class[\s]*?=\s*([\'\"\s])(.*?)\1[^>]*?> gets around most valid html if you're looking for a particular tag -> class  
  
Group 2 will match your class name and group 1 will be the delimiter (', ", space)  

For example, all of these:

http://regexr.com?34l34

Comment: This is a very good point. Using `BeautifulSoup` for example for Python, we are able to parse html tags and similar components from React Native that if you know how these .js files look like, they mix html tags and javascript/typescript together. However this library is happy to neglect all the rest of the javascript in the file and parse the react native components. So yes please use a good HTML parser indeed

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want. It is written for a Perl program, and the format may differ depending on what language you are using

```
/(?! [^>]+ \b(?:item|range)= ) (<[a-z]+.*?>) /igx
```

The code below demonstrates this pattern in a Perl program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = qr/ (?! [^>]+ \b(?:item|range)= ) (<[a-z]+.*?>) /ix;

my $str = <<'END';

<span class="inline prewrap strong">DATE:</span>    12/01/10
<span class="inline prewrap strong">MR:</span>  1234567
<span class="inline prewrap strong">DOB:</span> 12/01/65
<span class="inline prewrap strong">HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS:</span>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

<span class="inline prewrap strong">MEDICATIONS:</span>  <span term="Advil" range="true">Advil </span>and Ibuprofen.

END

print "$_\n" foreach $str =~ /$pattern/g;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<span class="inline prewrap strong">
<span class="inline prewrap strong">
<span class="inline prewrap strong">
<span class="inline prewrap strong">
<span class="inline prewrap strong">
```

Comment: this is not the output i want :) imagine if i do a replace with those results...i will have </span> all over the place. I solved my own problem, took some time but i did it. Italics or capitals, it is just a matter of perception. I personally like capitals because they just stand out. Some people are more sensitive about them... Since we're not using voice here i think you're going a bit too far interpreting my capitals as a sign of tone raising. But hey, we all live in our small digital world...aren't we?

Comment: You didn't originally mention anything about using the pattern to perform replacements. Please show your solution as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<\w+\s+(?!term).*?>(.*?)</.*?>
```

Comment: Doesn't allow for `<tag attribute1="value" term="text">`

Comment: doesn't have too, i am creating the <tag term="text"> so i know precisely what i'm looking for. there is no chance that another attribute will be along the "term" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex will work properly.

This regex will select style attribute of any HTML tag.

```
<\s*\w*\s*style.*?>
```

You can check this on https://regex101.com

Comment: That only works if `style` is the first attribute. It also won't work if the tag *name* includes `style`.

Comment: `<\s` is not a valid html tag.