# Detect XML fragments in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

Is there a reliable way to detect in C#/.NET whether a given piece of XML is rooted XML content or a non-rooted fragment?

Rooted content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>a</a>
</root>
```

Fragment:

```
<a>a</a>
<b>b</b>
<c>c</c>
```

I'm trying to identify these situations using the `XmlReader` and `XDocument` classes but I can't really distinguish between ordinary `XmlException`s and the one thrown when trying to load an otherwise valid fragment.

Comment: Regex can help you. [Using Regex to match xml tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008430/regex-to-match-html-tags-with-specific-attributes)

Comment: And what will you do with this information?

Comment: @Evk Based on it I will decide whether I can load it using `XmlDocument.Load()` if it's rooted, or using `XmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment()` if it's a fragment. I can't figure out though how to do the same with the Linq-to-XML classes such as `XDocument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use XmlReader, you can do it like this:

```
static bool IsXmlRooted(Stream st) {
    bool sawRoot = false;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(st, new XmlReaderSettings() {
        // fragment works for documents too
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    })) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            // if we see element at depth 0 - it's top-level element
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Depth == 0) {
                // if we already saw another top level element - that is fragment
                // can return fast
                if (sawRoot)
                    return false;
                sawRoot = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I've been looking for. I like that you don't always have to go through the entire XML before figuring out if it's rooted, and you don't have to load it all in memory either.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class XmlString
{
    public static bool IsFragment(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            XElement.Parse(xml);
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            XElement.Parse("<root>" + xml + "</root>");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Why not something as simple as:

Try to parse it. If it raises an exception, encapsulate it and try to parse it again. If it does parse, it was a collection of fragments made valid by encapsulating in a root tag.

Comment: This is actually pretty nice and simple. The only inconvenience I see is that it's not very friendly when you get the XML from a file or another stream. I was hoping I could do this using `XmlReader` and avoid reading the entire XML in memory (into a `string`).